# Append records of two columns

Tags: sql-server

How can I append records of two fields in single row.

Let's say, we have two columns in a table containing n number of records. I need to append each row having comma delimited in a single row.

```
Col1
Abs
Abd
Abf
Abg
```

```
Col2
10
15
20
0
```

Desired output

```
O/pcol
Abs:10 ;Abd:15 ;Abf:20 ;Abg:0
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be helpful

Comment: Please post sample data and expected output. Oh hey @John

Comment: Is this what you want?     SELECT FIELD1 + ', ' + FIELD2 FROM YOURTABLE

Comment: Re-writing the question might be a good idea. It's quite difficult to understand what you're trying to say. With proper examples, of course.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Concatenate many rows into a single text string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string)

Answer (score 1):

You can use an "accumulator" variable to concatenate all the values:

```
declare @testTable table (Col1 nvarchar(50),Col2 nvarchar(50))
declare @accumulator nvarchar(max)

insert into @testTable
          select 'Abs',10
union all select 'Abd',15
union all select 'Abf',20
union all select 'Abg',0

set @accumulator =''

select @accumulator = @accumulator + Col1 + ':' + Col2 + ' ;' from @testTable

select @accumulator
```

The output of this snippet should be:

> Abs:10 ;Abd:15 ;Abf:20 ;Abg:0 ;